# Entity Framework attempting to add records to wrong table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have never had an issue with Entity Framework attempting to save to the wrong table before. However, today I've run into this issue.

I am attempting to save to a table called `dbo.Accounts` in SQL Server and for some strange reason, the SQL that it creates is the following.

```
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);

MERGE [Accounts] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, 0),
(@p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, 1),
(@p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, 2)) AS i ([CreateDate], [LastUpdated], [Name], [ParentId], _Position) ON 1=0

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([CreateDate], [LastUpdated], [Name], [ParentId])
    VALUES (i.[CreateDate], i.[LastUpdated], i.[Name], i.[ParentId])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
    INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [i].[Id] FROM @inserted0 i
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];

INSERT INTO [AspNetUserRoles] ([RoleId], [UserId])
VALUES (@p12, @p13);
',N'@p0 datetime2(7),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(100),@p3 int,@p4 datetime2(7),@p5 datetime2(7),@p6 nvarchar(100),@p7 int,@p8 datetime2(7),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 nvarchar(100),@p11 int,@p12 nvarchar(450),@p13 nvarchar(450)',@p0='2022-01-27 11:19:59.5774258',@p1='2022-01-27 11:19:59.5774300',@p2=N'Test Account',@p3=1,@p4='2022-01-27 11:24:37.7412127',@p5='2022-01-27 11:24:37.7412136',@p6=N'test',@p7=1,@p8='2022-01-27 11:28:45.9794153',@p9='2022-01-27 11:28:45.9794169',@p10=N'test',@p11=1,@p12=N'5d0f3665-110a-4986-9bbf-3f2b7da0ccbf',@p13=N'db9f3ebb-3e0d-4972-a8f9-c7cdb10ed94f'
```

As you can see it's attempting to save the account, AND trying to create a UserRole.

The exception is the following:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]  
Failed executing DbCommand (39ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 450), @p1='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
INSERT INTO [AspNetUserRoles] ([RoleId], [UserId])  
VALUES (@p0, @p1);  
 
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]  
An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PipelineSolutions.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext'.  
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.  
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PipelineSolutions", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.  
 The statement has been terminated.

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)  
 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()  
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)  
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---  
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ClientConnectionId:dddf9058-bb37-477b-8a67-20b506e4efde

 Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16  
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PipelineSolutions", tab
    le "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
          The statement has been terminated.
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
             at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
             at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
             at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          ClientConnectionId:dddf9058-bb37-477b-8a67-20b506e4efde
          Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
             --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
          An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PipelineSolutions", tab
    le "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
          The statement has been terminated.
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
             at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
             at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
             at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          ClientConnectionId:dddf9058-bb37-477b-8a67-20b506e4efde
          Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
             --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at PipelineSolutions.DataAccess.Repository.AccountsRepository.CreateAsync(Account entity, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\James\source\repos\PiplelineSolutions\Server\PipelineSolutions.DataAccess\Repository\Accoun
    tsRepository.cs:line 40
             at PipelineSolutions.Controllers.Identity.AccountsController.Post(Account account, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\James\source\repos\PiplelineSolutions\Server\PipelineSolutions\Controllers\Identity\AccountsContro
    ller.cs:line 38
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted
    )
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
             at PipelineSolutions.Middleware.UserClaimsMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserManager`1 userManager) in C:\Users\James\source\repos\PiplelineSolutions\Server\PipelineSolutions\Middleware\UserClaimsMiddlewar
    e.cs:line 37
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
          An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PipelineSolutions.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext'.
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PipelineSolutions", tab
    le "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResultAsyncExecute(Task task, Object state)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeAsyncCall[T](AAsyncCallContext`1 context)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          ClientConnectionId:dddf9058-bb37-477b-8a67-20b506e4efde
          Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
             --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
           ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PipelineSolutions", tab
    le "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResultAsyncExecute(Task task, Object state)
             at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeAsyncCall[T](AAsyncCallContext`1 context)
          --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
          ClientConnectionId:dddf9058-bb37-477b-8a67-20b506e4efde
          Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
             --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)


And the code that I am calling:

    // Repository
    public override async Task<Account> CreateAsync (Account entity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

        if (entity.ParentId == 0) 
            entity.ParentId = 1;

        Context.Accounts.Add(entity);

        var a = await Context.SaveChangesAsync(token);

        return entity;
    }

    // ApplicationDbContext
    public virtual DbSet<Account>? Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(x => x.ChildAccounts)
            .WithOne(x => x.Parent);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .Property(x => x.ParentId)
            .IsRequired(false);
        //... other configuration
    }

    // model
    [Table("Accounts", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class Account:BaseEntity
    {
        [StringLength(100), Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public Account? Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Account>? ChildAccounts { get; set; }
    }
    

Why would this happen with only accounts, all of the other entities work correctly? Is there something in the name Account that is causing this issue?

**Update**

In the `ChangeTracker.DebugView` I see this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1] 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjmFW.png

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Post(T model, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model is IOwner owner)
                {
                    UpdateOwnerId(owner);
                }
                if (model.AccountId == 0)
                {
                    model.AccountId = AccountId;
                }
                var response = await Repository.CreateAsync(model, token);
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are the contents of the Change Tracker immediately before SaveChanges()?

Comment: I'm not sure. let me check I will update the question.

Comment: @3xGuy Have you tried the Fluent API way since it is the preferred option if you want to ensure your Domain Model stays uncluttered:  `modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Accounts");`. Also, adding to this, if you want to remove the pluralization of your table names: `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`

Comment: Something is missing. What is happening upstream from CreateAsync()? Can you new up Context within the method just for testing purposes? https://gist.github.com/mxmissile/a0beb532ca3a95fb3b19cfcbdd3dbe3b 

Or possibly create an isolated unit test that demonstrated the issue?

Comment: @mxmissile I have updated the question with the controller call

Comment: @RahulSharma `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` is not an option, and yes I have added `.ToTable`

Comment: thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I found the issue because of your comment. The `UserRoles ` were being changed somewhere else in the application and I found the issue. If you would like to write up an answer, I will accept it. thank you again!